Ansible navigator execution environment crashing after 05m03s (docker & macos)
I've created two roles to provision aws RDS instances with users, and permissions.
These permissions are set a different levels.
Thing is, now that we have more stuff to provision, the docker container exits after running 05m03s.
This happens for both mysql and pg roles.
There are no logs at the ansible level, it just exists with error with a message to check the logs, and the logs just stop when it exits.
It seems to me this is either an issue with docker or with the base image (using fedora 39).
In addition, since docker usage is abstracted by ansible-navigator, I can t exec into the container after crash to debug.
Anyone could help in which way I could go about debugging this issue?
This is running on macos.
Executing the roles against several instances individually, works fine.
Timing the execution and noticed that if crashes without fail after 05m03s execution time.

It was a configuration in ansible.cfg
ansible-runner:
  artifact-dir: /tmp/test1
  rotate-artifacts-count: 10
  timeout: 300

